# Compare dates db2/400 vs SQL Server

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I want to compare a date/time from SQL Server (type datetime-16) with db2/400 (type Z).

Typically I would like to know that that there are 60 seconds between 18:44 and 18:45

Each one has slightly different display characteristics.

```
SQL Server  2016-07-26 18:45:00.000
Db2/400     2016-07-26-18.45.00.000000
```

If I do this on my db2 database:

```
 SELECT 
     MYDATETIME, 
     '2016-07-26 18:44:00.000', 
     MYDATETIME -  '2016-07-26 18:44:00.000' 
 FROM @dates
```

I get this

```
 MYDATETIME                  Constant value                  Numeric Expression     
 2016-07-26-18.45.00.000000  2016-07-26 18:44:00.000                 100.000000
```

Db2 SQL seems quite generous to accept slightly different formats.

But query tells me that 1 minute difference = 100.  Looks like I have a base 10 comparison happening here.

Using db2 timestamp function, I get the same result

```
SELECT 
    MYDATETIME, 
    '2016-07-26 18:44:00.000', 
    MYDATETIME - timestamp('2016-07-26-18.44.00.000000') 
FROM @dates
```

How can I make comparisons that would give me difference in minutes (or hours or days)?

Comment: It's actually [giving you a formatted value](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_timestampdiff.html): `100.000000` is actually `1 minutes`, `00 seconds`, `000000 fractional seconds`.  Note that the value is relative (ie, '1 month'), so maybe not useful.  Why do you want the difference anyways?

Comment: Clockwork - I want to ask questions like "How long since last run", "show me transactions from last 24 hours" , "Extraction was run yesterday at 2PM. Show me what is new.". Thanks

Comment: You almost never want to use a diff in a query, because it's going to cause the db to ignore indicies.  Generally, you want to construct the limits and do a range query.  Application-layer languages have better ways to get duration diffs than pretty much all RDBMSs, so do the math at display-time only.  How are you trying to communicate between the two dbs anyways?  Why not just pass the required start/end values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is DB2/400, but in my experience the time operators work the same way, so from [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html):

```
SELECT 
    MYDATETIME, 
    '2016-07-26 18:44:00.000', 
    MYDATETIME - timestamp('2016-07-26-18.44.00.000000') SECONDS
FROM @dates
```

Since I don't have a DB2 instance to test this on, the next thing I would try would be this:

```
SELECT 
    MYDATETIME, 
    '2016-07-26 18:44:00.000', 
    SECOND(MYDATETIME - timestamp('2016-07-26-18.44.00.000000'))
FROM @dates
```

Comment: The value returned from the difference is essentially a formatted value - the `100` the OP is seeing isn't the number of seconds, but `1 minute, 0 seconds`.  That's if those statement even run; I rather suspect syntax errors, given you need an actual time/timestamp value to attach the operator to.

Answer (score 4):

The results of subtracting two timestamps on DB2 for IBM i is known as a [duration](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzdtdur.htm)

You might find [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzscatimedifstmp.htm) useful

```
select                                                           
   timestampdiff(2                                               
                , char(timestamp('2016-07-27 08:35:00.000000')   
                        - timestamp('2016-07-27 08:34:00.000000')
                      )                                          
                )                                                
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

note that the first parameter is a small int with the following values

```
1   Microseconds
2   Seconds
4   Minutes
8   Hours
16  Days
32  Weeks
64  Months
128 Quarters
256 Years
```

The second parameter must be a character representation of a duration.

**EDIT** As pointed out by Clockwork-Muse, `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` is best used for short durations less than a month.

If you need accurate calculation for longer values, use the following form:

```
(DAYS(t1) - DAYS(t2)) * 86400 + 
(MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(t1) - MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(t2))
```

Sample

```
select                                                           
    (DAYS(timestamp('2016-07-27 08:35:00.000000'))               
      - DAYS(timestamp('2015-07-27 08:35:00.000000'))            
    ) * 86400 +                                                  
    (MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(timestamp('2016-07-27 08:35:00.000000'))   
     - MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(timestamp('2015-07-27 08:35:00.000000')))
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Comment: `TIMESTAMPDIFF` is next to useless with anything separated by more than a month, given its use of estimates (and the duration).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, but the OP is looking at a duration of only 60 seconds.  I've add an alternative...